# How to add transitions to a react scroll event

Tags: reactjs

I have a div that disappears on scroll, but it just jumps away, id like to customize the transition to fade out

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    scrolled: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmout() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll = () => this.setState({ scrolled: true });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!this.state.scrolled && <img src="..." />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This will help you - https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use css way to solve the problem

for example you can use npm classnames

```
import cn from 'classnames';
// ...your code

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src="..." className={cn({ animatedFadeOutClass: this.state.scrolled })} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

and css

```
.animatedFadeOutClass {
   transition: 0.5s;
   opacity: 0;
   height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

or using https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html and npm react-addons-transition-group